# DirectSoundBuffer8::Lock/Unlock

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw32, mingw-w64, directsound

My question is generally about how the behavior of [Lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectsoundbuffer8.idirectsoundbuffer8.lock%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Unlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectsoundbuffer8.idirectsoundbuffer8.unlock%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of DirectSoundBuffer8 like.

I have something like this:

```
unsigned char *bufferPtr;

result = ((IDirectSoundBuffer8*)dsb)->Lock(0,size,(void**)&bufferPtr,(DWORD*)&size, NULL, 0, 0);
if(FAILED(result)) {
    return;
}
memcpy(bufferPtr, waveData, size);
result = ((IDirectSoundBuffer8*)dsb)->Unlock((void*)bufferPtr, size, NULL, 0);
if(FAILED(result)) {
    return;
}
delete[] bufferPtr;
```

Do I have to really do `delete[] bufferPtr;` even if it is not made with `new`?

I compile my program using mingw. The 32-bit runs OK with the `delete[] bufferPtr;` but in the 64-bit build, it crashes.

Hope someone can enlighten me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you absolutely don't have to do `delete[] bufferPtr`. You don't own that memory, and once you've called `Unlock` your pointer to it is not even valid any more.